# Set Value of Dynamically Populated Select in Knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

So I'm using KnockoutJS to populate a `<select>` with options and to get the value of the select.

```
<select data-bind="enable: cols1().length > 0, options: cols1(), optionsText: 'name', value: jCol1" id="col1"></select>
```

The variable `cols1` holds objects with the simple format of `{ name: "name" }` just because it needs to be objects for some of the other stuff I do on the page. Is there any way to set the value of the select from outside of the data-binds on this element?

Comment: if `jCol1` is an observable, you can jus set the value like `jCol1('name')`. this will update the select and shows 'name' as selected option

Answer (score 1):

The `value` part of the binding says:

*Store a reference to an item that is in `cols1` in `jCol1`*

If you want to change the selection from outside of the UI, you'll have to set `jCol1` to a value that is in the `cols1` array. If you try to set it to anything else, knockout will reset it to the first value immediately. Switch out the commented lines of code in the example below to see this happen:

```js
var ViewModel = function() {
  this.options = ko.observableArray([
    { name: "Item 1" },
    { name: "Item 2" },
    { name: "Item 3" }
  ]);
  
  this.selection = ko.observable();
  this.selection.subscribe(function(newValue) { 
    console.log(newValue) 
  });
  
  this.changeSelectionFromOutside = function() {
    // This does not work because knockout does not do a 
    // deep comparison of objects
    // this.selection({ name: "Item 3" });  
    
    // This _does_ work, because it references one of the
    // options objects
    this.selection(this.options()[2]);
  }.bind(this);
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>


<select data-bind="options: options, value: selection, optionsText: 'name'"></select>

<button data-bind="click: changeSelectionFromOutside">
  Set option 3
</button>
```

Now, you can also choose to just store a string ID (or other primitive) of your selection. This makes it easier to set things from the outside, because you only need the ID instead of a reference to the actual item:

```js
var ViewModel = function() {
  this.options = ko.observableArray([
    { name: "Item 1" },
    { name: "Item 2" },
    { name: "Item 3" }
  ]);
  
  this.selection = ko.observable();
  this.selection.subscribe(function(newValue) { 
    console.log(newValue) 
  });
  
  this.changeSelectionFromOutside = function() {
    this.selection("Item 3");
  }.bind(this);
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<select data-bind="options: options, value: selection, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'name'"></select>

<button data-bind="click: changeSelectionFromOutside">
  Set option 3
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's use the states example:

```
//list of US states in array
self.usStates = [
        { StateName: 'Alabama', Abbr: 'AL' },
        { StateName: 'Alaska', Abbr: 'AK' },
        ...
//observable from that array
self.States = ko.observableArray(self.usStates);
//the selected state
self.selectedState = ko.observable();

//set selectedState from some value received from server
self.selectedState(self.States.find("Abbr", { StateName: "", Abbr: '<<Value i.e. TX>>' }).Abbr);
//finds TX, sets state to 'Texas'

//find custom function used to find specific object in array
ko.observableArray.fn.find = function (prop, data) {
        var valueToMatch = data[prop];
        return ko.utils.arrayFirst(this(), function (item) {
            return item[prop] === valueToMatch;
        });
 };
```

This may be overly complicated for what you're looking to do, but this is how I do it when I want to choose a value from a select based on a value from the record in the database.